# The range when excuteing From / Size in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, full-text-search

When I reading the theory of From / Size in elasticsearch.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/search-request-from-size.html

The issue is that how to detemine the range of searching. For example, if I generate 1.000 records then I query it as snippets below:

```
{
    "from" : 100, "size" : 10,
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}
```

Is that it will be searching on the range of record 100 to 1.000 and then return 10 results ? Or it will automatically generate suitable range and return 10 results ?
Can anyone help me to get around this issue ? Best regard.

Answer (score 1):

So, elasticsearch splits our index into smaller parts called "shards", so if you have an index with 5 shards and 1000 documents each shard will be assigned 200 documents. Now when you execute a search query elasticsearch will search all the shards and create a list of result sorted in the descending order of the score in every shard.

Now if we want the first 10 results (from: 0, size:10), elasticsearch will get the top 10 results from each shard i.e. is total of 50 results(assuming each shard has more than 10 hits), then sort them again and return the top 10 out of those and discard the rest of the 40 results.

Now in case you want the results from 100 to 110(from:100, size:10), elasticsearch will request the top 110 result from each shard ie. a total of 550 results. These 550 results will now be sorted again to get the top 110 results and the rest of the 440 results will be discarded.

Now out of these 110 results, number 1-99 will be discarded and the result number 100-110 will be returned as the result of the search query.

Comment: In your answer "Now in case you want the results from 100 to 110(from:100, size:10), elasticsearch will request the top 110 result from each shard ie. a total of 550 results" have problem.
I think it elasticsearch will request the top 10 results because of the size:10 you was config. And the total just 50 results collected from all shards

Comment: Well, that's not correct. Just take a look at this : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/pagination.html